# Positioning Photos in a Grid (HTML)

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

I've been trying to code [this page](http://danoc.me) for a while, but my biggest problem is that I can't seem to get the photos perfectly positioned. For some reason, there is a small bottom padding in each `<td>` which is messing things up.

Here is the table code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="height:353px;"><img src="danoconnor/img/photography/farm.jpg" height="353" width="470" alt="Farm" /></td>
        <td><img src="danoconnor/img/photography/paragliding.jpg" height="190" width="254" alt="Paraglider" /></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><img src="danoconnor/img/photography/cristo.jpg" height="353" width="230" alt="Cristo Redentor" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="danoconnor/img/photography/u2.jpg" height="154" width="254" alt="U2 at Fordham University" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My question is: how can I make [the photogrid](http://danoc.me) look like this:

[image]?

Comment: You really should use CSS to position <div> tags that hold your images.  Html <table>s were made for displaying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using css, you can still do it by changing the opening table tag to:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

I'd also add valign="bottom" to the last td tag, to make sure that image doesn't have space underneath it:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><img src="danoconnor/img/photography/u2.jpg" height="154" width="254" alt="U2 at Fordham University" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Actually, this seems more like a problem with the `<article>` or `<section>` tags I've been using. I'm going to work around this using your suggestion, and just playing around with the paddings until I find something that works. Thanks!

Comment: By default, images as well as text are aligned with a baseline value. Quite useful as long as there is text, but not so much when there are only images. `vertical-align: top;` or `bottom` will indeed solve the problem (or that bad ol' valign attribute)